# Receive notifications near places without check-in?

Tags: foursquare

I'm new to foursquare api. Is it possible to write an application that would receive push notifications from foursquare if the user has appeared near some place and did check-in in it? That is, he just downloaded this app and if appeared near some place that receives notice that near such a place?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Foursquare API doesn't support this ability. Our currently supported real-time options are for when users check in to places or leave content at venues (only if you're a venue manager)